# modal height doesn't fit to content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal (using twitter bootstrap) that works fine on other pages, but this particular page, the modal height is elongated, as a result the content in the body is displayed at the bottom of the modal, resulting a large whitespace between the beginning and the end.

Here is the modal css

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1050;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 560px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #999;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
outline: none;
```

on the view, shows a height of 560px:

```
<div id="form" class="modal hide fade in" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
<div id="form">
test
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it normal that there is a dot before `position`?

Comment: oh i accidentally pasted in here. So that's not the problem..

Comment: I still don't know where your problem comes from but you have twice the same 'form' ID. An ID is supposed to be unique.

Comment: oh oops, yes, i actually removed that too.. that's not the problem either.

Comment: If you use firebug, or the chrome developer tools, what's above "test" ? There is something filling this area.

Comment: nothing is in thee.. just "test"

Comment: Does the form starts just above test?

Comment: form starts where the modal begins.